# retrieve all areas where id's don't exist in supplied list

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm sure I must be missing something really simple here..

OK I have a list of AreaIds. I want to compare that list to the MapArea Table and return any IDs that exist in the table but NOT in the supplied list.

This is my list of supplied areas that I want to check:

```
 var currentAreas = (from c in _entities.mapAreaLink
                            where c.listingId == id
                            select new
                                {
                                    c.MapArea.areaId
                                }
                            ).ToList();
```

This is the getting the exhaustive list of mapAreas..

```
  var availableAreas = (from m in _entities.MapAreas
                              select new
                                  {
                                      m.areaId
                                  }
                                  ).ToList();
```

This compares the two lists and gets items that exist in the maparea table but not in the maparealink (constrained by an id of the item I am looking at).

```
var unusedAreas = availableAreas.Except(currentAreas).ToList();
```

I seem to get the list back ok, but what I need to do is now return a list of maparea objects based on the results of the Except.tolist above.

I thought I could do this:

```
        var mapareas = (from e in _entities.MapAreas
                        where unusedAreas.Contains(e.areaId)            
                        select e).ToList();
```

I am getting an ambiguous invocation on the where & "Cannot resolve method Contains(int)" on the e.areaId.

Ive tried using:

```
var unusedAreas = availableAreas.Except(currentAreas).ToArray();
```

No Joy.. Can anyone help me out here - I am guessing I must be missing a fundamental basic here.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create anonymous types with just one `int` property. That's not necessary and it causes the later problem. If you create lists of `int` you'll be OK:

```
var currentAreas = (from c in _entities.mapAreaLink
                    where c.listingId == id
                    select c.MapArea.areaId).ToList();
var availableAreas = (from m in _entities.MapAreas
                      select m.areaId).ToList();
```